# Problem sending ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My problem is I got 2 link call the same function, but in first link I can see ajax request in firebug(run fine) but in second query, my ajax totally won't show in firebug(request won sent out) and alert me 0,error,undefined.

However I already try both of my link, its valid and can be surf.

#### HTML

```
<a onclick="friend_act(url3)">test</a>
<a onclick="friend_act(url4)">test2</a>
```

#### JS

```
function friend_act(url2){
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:url2,
   data: {ao:1,msg:1},
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: ShowLoading,
   success: function(resp){
       $('#theLoading').dialog('close');
       $('#loading').html('');
       //add friend

   },
    error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
       alert(xhr.status);
        alert(ajaxOptions);
                alert(thrownError);
       $('#theLoading').dialog('close');
       $('#loading').html('');
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Can we have a look at the HTML structure? And please add some more info about the error alert you are receiving.

Comment: This looks fine. Could you give us the URLs? Or sample ones?

Comment: Can you do `alert(url2);` in your `friend_act` function to see what URL is being passed for the second link?

Comment: haiz i also wish to show you my link, but my comp privacy guildline not allow

Comment: paste the ulr2 and url3 into your code like `var url2 = "index.php"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i simplified your problem. here is a working example. Maybe this can get you goiing..

http://jsfiddle.net/SjE7f/

Comment: it look like <a onclick="friend('http://www.kernel.org')">test</a> because status is 0

Comment: hi i think i know the problem, is because, the link come from 2 different comment links.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the browser does not allow you **cross domain requests**.
If your URL points out of your domain, the request will be **disabled**.